# USBWebserver Runtime error 75

Tags: php, apache

I am using USBWebserver. I have made the necessary configuration and my php application runs on a my pc. Now I copied the files  to a CD and tried to run it buut I get Run-time error 75
Path/File access error.
I have searched on the interenet for a solution and tried this [one](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-performance/how-can-you-fix-the-run-time-error-75-pathfile/db00f993-c6ea-455e-bd9d-5c2d013ecf23) but it has not worked for me.

Comment: You have to be an admin user

Comment: I am logged in as an administrator.

Comment: The author can be e-mailed at mail@usbwebserver.net